# Examples of Web App using Azure Cognitive Services Translator Text API

Tags: azure, microsoft-translator, azure-cognitive-services

Does anyone have an code examples of a web app using the Azure Cognitive Services - Translator Text API?  I found the UWP and console apps but can't find any web examples.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately, this type of question (tutorial/example/etc recommendation question) is expressly off-topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

The Node.js samples may be close enough to pure web app client code to get you going:

[Node JS Sample](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/NodeJs-Example)

[Node JS Quick Start](https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/Documentation-Code-TextAPI/tree/master/quickstarts/NodeJS)